# expo app not running on dev build:unexpected end of stream EXPO

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, expo, android-emulator

I'm encountering an issue when running my Expo development environment with the command `npx expo start --dev-client`. The command executes without any apparent problems, but when I try to access my development app, I receive an "unexpected end of stream" error at my designated IP address.

Here's a screenshot of the error message:

[image]

In an attempt to troubleshoot the issue, I altered the port by executing `npx expo start --dev-client --localhost --port 8000`, but this did not resolve the problem. Could anyone please provide some guidance on what might be causing this error and suggest potential fixes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've solved this using:`npx expo start --dev-client --tunnel --clear` (the clear flag is not necessary)

Comment: Thank you buddy!! Works like a charm! BTW, may I ask what caused this error?

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading node to v18.16.0 works around the issue for me.

Comment: This same issue happened for me too.  I had upgraded to Node version 20 before and when this started happening.  Once I downgraded to 19.9.0, my app loaded fine.